# To get the unique number of records using awk

Tags: shell, awk

cat z.txt

```
2017-02-06 21:27:43,100,3,9,2,2222223196
2017-02-06 21:27:46,101,3,11,2,2222223196
2017-02-06 21:27:43,100,3,9,2,2222223188
2017-02-06 21:27:43,100,3,9,2,2222223177
```

I have a file 'z.txt' having above records,
I want to check how many records there are where field4 has a value of 9.

There is 1 condition -> if 'field 4 is having value 9' AND in another record 'field 4 is having value 11' & both having same field 6.I n this case record 1 & 2, having same field 6, so they should be omitted.

In output I want, below 2 fields only, where for unique field 6, only value 9 has come in field 4

```
2017-02-06 21:27:43,100,3,9,2,2222223188
2017-02-06 21:27:43,100,3,9,2,2222223177
```

I want to acheive this using awk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, '$4==9   {v[$6]=$0} 
           a[$6]++ {delete v[$6]} 
           END     {for(k in v) if(a[k]==1) print v[k]}' file

2017-02-06 21:27:43,100,3,9,2,2222223177
2017-02-06 21:27:43,100,3,9,2,2222223188
```

note that the order is not preserved due to associative array, there are ways to fix it but not sure it's worth the effort.

Comment: @karakfa.1 more query, in above case we had ignored 1st 2 records as field 6 was same in both the records,but now i want to add a condition where say,if 1st record has timestamp 2017-02-06 21:27:43 & 2nd record has timestamp 2017-02-06 21:27:44, now the time difference between both the records was only 1second,but say if the time difference is going above 2minutes,[field4 = value 9 & field 4 = value 11 {in this case both having same field 6}] then print this record too, which having field4 = value 9,So the desired output would be, 
1st record, 3rd reccord, & 4th record [field4=value9 records

Comment: that's not how SO works! Create a new question with that variation and you may reference to this one.  If this answers the question as posted above up vote and/or accept it.  Alternatively, if you think it's wrong down vote it and I'll remove it.